# Why my rspec test fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing a test for my ShowcasesController, and I'm stuck in "GET new" action, for sign in user.

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

RSpec.describe ShowcasesController, type: :controller do

  context "user is signed in" do

    before do
      @user = create(:user)
      @admin = create(:admin)
      @showcase = create(:showcase)
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      sign_in(@user)
    end

    describe "GET new" do
      context "user is not admin" do
        it "redirect to root page" do
          get :new
          expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url)
        end
      end

      context "user is an admin" do
        it "expose a new showcase" do
          sign_in(@admin)
          get :new
          expect(controller.showcase).to be_a_new(Showcase)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

For unknown reason, my test fail and I'm reciving this error massage:

> Failures:
>
> 1) ShowcasesController user is signed in GET new user is an admin
>   expose a new showcase
>        Failure/Error: expect(controller.showcase).to be_a_new(Showcase)
>
> ```
>  NoMethodError:
>    undefined method `showcase' for #<ShowcasesController:0x00000004d7c400>
>  # ./spec/controllers/showcases_controller_spec.rb:104:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

```
class ShowcasesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @showcases = Showcase.all
  end

  def show
    @showcase = Showcase.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @showcase = Showcase.new
  end

  def create
    @showcase = Showcase.new(showcase_params)
    if @showcase.save
    end
  end

  def edit
    @showcase = Showcase.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @showcase = Showcase.find(params[:id])
    if @showcase.update_attributes(showcase_params)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @showcase = Showcase.find(params[:id]).destroy
  end

  private

  def showcase_params
    params.require(:showcase).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :sport_club, :email, :pass_exam_date, :pass_exam_location,
    :exam_type, :level, :first_graduation_date, :second_graduation_date, :third_graduation_date, :fourth_graduation_date,
    :total_match_number, :match_number_in_last_season)
  end

  def correct_user
    unless current_user.admin?
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the controller?

Comment: I guess you meant `assigns(:showcase)` instead of `controller.showcase`? Just because you set the instance variable doesn't mean it is accessible through a reader. On top of that you might want to clean up your `before` block and use `let` little bit more to avoid unnecessary db operations in your tests.

Comment: Now it works. Unfortunately I was using outdated tutorial. Now I'm going to refactor my code with your suggestions. Can you put your answer as in separate answer, so I can accept this as proper answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `showcase` method defined on your controller, there is only an instance variable.

To check instance variables on the controller, rspec controller test provides `assigns` function:

```
expect(assigns :showcase).to be_a_new(Showcase)
```

Note: As far as I am aware, there are currently some plans to remove `assigns` from rspec. I believe that the decision is made because it violates "don't test private implementation details" - I personally dislike this decision a lot, as it will make controller unit testing much harder. IMO, Even though it is instance variable, it is being used to communicate between controller and a view and as such is part of controller public API. (Putting on side that using instance variables for public API sucks as hell).

Comment: (Putting on side that using instance variables for public API sucks as hell) <- YES!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the method `showcase` has not been defined for the `ShowcasesController`. More precisely, an accessor has not been defined for the `showcase` property of the controller.

```
An example with an accessor
class ShowcasesController
  attr_accessor :showcase

  # other controller methods
end
```